# How to edit the smart object in this Photoshop template?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject

I'm completely new to Photoshop and I've been trying to replace the image in a template with my screenshot.

I went through other questions here and elsewhere online and learnt the basics of using a smart object.

I've tried to do the same with other PSD templates I obtained online to see if I'm doing it right and I was clearly successful. But I tried the same with this particular file and I am unable to get the right output.

Can someone please provide a step by step instruction of how to handle this particular file?

PSD template: http://bit.ly/1gPdIl5 (Moto 360 Product Template.psd)

My Image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Choose Layer→Smart Objects→Edit Contents.

or

Simply double-click the Smart Objects layer thumbnail in the Layers panel.

Comment: Hi Andrew. Thanks for your response. I did that. Opened the 'watch face smart object'.
It opens the Ellipse 11.psb file to be edited. I even went ahead and opened the guides - EPS smart object. I problem I have is that I'm not sure how to place my screenshot in here. In which layer and How, I'm unaware of. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Double-click the smart layer thumbnail and a dialog should pop up. With that dialog open, go to the Photoshop top menu and click File>Place Embedded. Navigate to your image, click to select it, then click the Place button in the dialog. Once your image is imported, resize it as needed. Then from the menu, click Save.

Comment: Hi Diana, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!